# Angular Material outlined input and ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-material-6

I have an Angular app ^6.0.0 with Angular Material ^6.0.2 and ngx-translate ^10.0.2.

In my app, I have some mat-inputs with appearance="outline". Whenever I change the language of the app, the input label truncates with the field outline, as in the screenshot below.

If I refresh the page the outline takes the width of the current language and it works as is should.

Is there any way to refresh/rebuild only the inputs when I change the language, without having to refresh the page?

Thanks!

Label normal in french:

[image: Label normal in french]

Label truncates with outline in English:

[image: Label truncates with outline in English]

Comment: Please try to provide relevant sample code so people can help you better

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for the reply. I've added a stackblitz example of the problem:[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-translate-issue)

The app starts in english. If you click the FR button on the top right and then select the input you'll be able to see the problem with the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MatFormField provides a function for this - `updateOutlineGap()`. You can call the function after changing the language using a timeout:

Template:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" #formField="matFormField">
    <mat-label>{{ 'search' | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food">
</mat-form-field>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('formField') formField: MatFormField;

changeToFr() {
    this.translate.use('fr');
    setTimeout(() => this.formField.updateOutlineGap());
}
```

Here is your example on Stackblitz updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-translate-issue-1uamsu.

Comment: Why the `setTimeout`, @g-tranter? Indeed, it doesn't work without it.

Comment: The translate feature is asynchronous, so the label change does not get applied immediately, and therefore it is necessary to wait before attempting to use the label to calculate the the outline gap size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried with something sync and `setTimeout` seems to be needed as well. Any idea why? An [example Slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-translate-issue-ymtonf). Do you think I should open an issue?

Comment: Sometimes when you call a function synchronously, the changes that result are asynchronous. This is often the case in Angular when changing something that affects the display.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm honestly not convinced :). Even if the change is asynchronous, the outline should fix itself after a while, or I'm not understanding you. To future readers: probably should ask another question with it. If you do, kindly link it here.

Comment: Why would the outline gap 'fix itself'? You are making an assumption that isn't true about how and when the outline gap size is calculated. The calculation is made synchronously when you invoke the update function. If the label change is asynchronous, the calculation may happen before the label is actually changed, so the size is based on the old label. Change detection does not update the gap size except when the DOM is not stable (right after init or on appearance change perhaps). Look at the form field source code and you'll become 'convinced'. The proof is in the pudding.

Comment: Thank you very much explanation, now I get it!

Comment: If i've more than one mat-form-field, i't not work with rest mat-form-field. only work with first mat-form-field

Comment: @DucNguyen use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: @G.Tranter it is not recalculated, when the field is filled with any value. On your stackblitz example Try to type any text in the field and then click on FR.